# Read DICOM images

Tags: vtk, dicom, imaging, itk

i am trying to read dicom images without using imageviewer and i came across VtkGdmReader.. when i am trying to execute it, its giving me an error:

code => [vtkGdmReader](http://www.creatis.insa-lyon.fr/software/public/Gdcm/html.developper/DoxyVtkGdmReaderExamples.html) example

error C2039: 'SetInput' : is not a member of 'vtkTexture'

error C2039: 'SetInput' : is not a member of 'vtkPolyDataMapper'

please can any one tell me why am i facing this problem, is this error related to vtk version ? if so then how can i go about it ?

please help me resolving the problem..

Comment: I believe SetInput was removed in VTK-6. http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Replacement_of_SetInput

Comment: @user2268891: I think that drescherjm is right. I am using VTK 5.10.1 and I can use vtkPolyDataMapper->SetInput() without problem (my Intellisense also recognizes it on its own). Probably, you should revert to VTK 5.x.x to make that example work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, this error is related to the VTK version. [`SetInput()` was removed in VTK 6](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Replacement_of_SetInput).

You can either work in VTK 5 or update the code. If you decide to update it, this error gets fixed by replacing `SetInput()` with either `SetInputData()` or `SetInputConnection()` with a few modifications. You should use `SetInputConnection()` if you want the filters to go through the pipeline.

As an example of fixing the errors you mentioned, you should replace the following lines in the code you provided:
`VTKtexture->SetInput(ima);`  and
`VTKplaneMapper->SetInput(VTKplane->GetOutput());`
to:
`VTKtexture->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());` and
`VTKplaneMapper->SetInputConnection(VTKplane->GetOutputPort());`

In the second modification (`VTKplaneMapper`), note that we just changed `GetOutput()` to `GetOutputPort()`, while in the first one (`VTKtexture`) we completely changed the argument passed to `SetInputConnection()`. That happens because data objects (such as `ima`) no longer have dependency on pipeline objects (such as algorithms and executives). In this case, we give the algorithm that generated that data object as the argument - if you look for it, you can see the line `vtkImageData* ima = reader->GetOutput();`, you just have to replace `GetOutput()` by `GetOutputPort()` as we did in the second modification.

I recommend looking into the VTK Wiki's [VTK 6 Migration pages](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Overview) (and [guide](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration_Guide)) for more information on this error and other errors that you might run into.